# Trying to call the stored procedure from C# windows form but nothing happens

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a stored procedure from a C# windows Form application. It gets executed but nothing happens up in the database i.e no records are added to the table.
Here's my C# code:

```
private void buttonAddData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string actionTaken = "Added";
    string changeDescription = "Added new Code";
    string updatedBy = "ICherry";
    string currentStatus = "In development";
    SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ConfigData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = conDatabase.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "spLogConfigChanges";                
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActionTaken",actionTaken);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChangeDescription", changeDescription);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdatedBy", updatedBy);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentStatus", currentStatus);
        conDatabase.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection opened");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Command Executed");
        conDatabase.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And my SP when executed in Query analyser runs with no errors and I can see the records being created.

Comment: @paqogomez- yes, it works perfectly fine in SSMS.

Comment: Do you need to open the connection before creating the command? I'm looking at a bunch of examples that show this. Also, if you wrap your SqlConnection in a `using` statement you don't have to worry about calling  `Close()`, or `Close()` not being called if an exception is thrown.

Comment: are the parameters the same when you use Query Analyzer?

Comment: what does  `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` return. Does it return -1

Comment: @Bond- Yes the parameters are same when I run the sp in Query analyser

Comment: @user2526236-yes it returns -1

Comment: what happens if you change this line `SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ConfigData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");` to the following 
`SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ConfigData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");` notice the `"\\"` after LocalDb

Comment: Run the sql profiler and find out if the command is executing with the right parameters as you would on the SSMS

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same mdf file in .NET and SSMS?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of using

```
        SqlCommand cmd = conDatabase.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "spLogConfigChanges";                
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActionTaken",actionTaken);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChangeDescription", changeDescription);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdatedBy", updatedBy);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentStatus", currentStatus);
        conDatabase.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection opened");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Command Executed");
        conDatabase.Close();
```

try this:

```
conDatabase.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spLogConfigChanges",conDatabase);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActionTaken",SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = actionTaken;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ChangeDescription",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = changeDescription;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UpdateBy",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = updatedBy;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CurrentStatus",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=currentStatus);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Command Executed");
conDatabase.Close();
```

if you encounter some errors please comment

Comment: I haven't seen any errors but the same nothing gets added to the DB.

Comment: @MethodMan- When I add '\\' before the localDB , it says 'A network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. the server was not found or was not accessible.' so, probably it doesn't like the '\\' in connection string.

Comment: @iCherry are you using SQL Server? if yes change your connection string to 
@"DataSource = LocalDB;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;IntegratedSecutiy=TRUE";

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was using `stored procedure` I solved it by

**changing this**

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", "String Value")
```

**to this**

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "String Value";
```